# How to get specific text among full text in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the below string and i want to get just 'Tulips.jpg' from the entire text. file name may vary based on file name...  I mean... instead of tulip.jpg, it may be 'soemething.png'

i just want to get file name of the image or video from the below string. Any help please?

sample 1

```
http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/nxbigfile/default/b7795495-17f8-4bd7-89a9-82ef9a2ed840/file:content/Tulips.jpg?63038467.509013735
```

sample 2

```
http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/nxbigfile/default/b75830ca-caa9-4084-98bb-12dc9c6a7679/file:content/mov_bbb%20-%20Copy.mp4?63038467.509013735
```

Comment: do you have the query paramater or key? How do you know every time it will be Tulips.jpg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var urlImg = "http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/nxbigfile/default/b7795495-17f8-4bd7-89a9-82ef9a2ed840/file:content/Tulips.jpg?63038467.5090137";
// or get the current url
// var urlImg = window.location.href;

var startTag = "file:content/";
var endTag = "?";

var indexStart = urlImg.indexOf(startTag) + startTag.length;
var indexEnd = urlImg.indexOf(endTag);

var imgName = urlImg.substring(indexStart, indexEnd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will be helpful.res return an array of all matched word

```
(function(){
var string ="http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/nxbigfile/default/b7795495-17f8-4bd7-89a9-82ef9a2ed840/file:content/Tulips.jpg?63038467.509013735";
    var res = string.match(/Tulips.jpg/g);
    console.log(res[0]);

}())
```

if you directly want to read the url from browser,
 `set var string =windows.location.href`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwgx43x4/)